# median value for CPU utilization in Azure Data Explorer using KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

We have kusto Metrics table in our Kusto Explorer with the columns

```
EventTime   
ClusterName 
MetricName  
TimeGrain   
Average 
Minimum 
Maximum 
Count   
Total   
IngestionTime
```

We are trying to find a median value for CPU utilization with the metric values mentioned above. Any KQL queries to calculate the same?

Comment: you can calculate the median of the average cpu utilization using `percentile` operator. Note that it's not actually the median - that depends on the relative sizes of the original data average was calculated on

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response rony.Could you please share a query of the same as im unaware of what metric needs to be considered to take the percentiles.So my requirement is to get percetiles of CPU utilization at 20,40,50,90.Based on these percentile values we are trying to get a median value and define thresholds according and set up alerting mechanisms.So should i be taking percentiles on Average or which column?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot tell you how to calculate what you need because i do not know anything about your data...